# sql queries please, i have tried but i am unable to get it

Tags: mysql

Find all managers for which all the employees they manage share the same office. You should return their eid, their name, and the office where all their managed people are located.

```
SELECT e.eid    AS ID,
       e.NAME   AS NAME,
       e.office AS office
FROM   employee e,
       manager m
WHERE  e.eid = m.mid
GROUP  BY m.mid;
```

Is the above query is right??

Comment: Why don’t you execute it and tell us?

Comment: [*Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: *"Is the above query is right??"*  No most likely not see [MySQL manual off GROUP BY handling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) unless functionally dependent

Comment: Also you should not be using the old implicit ANSI comma join annymore, use explicit `... JOIN .. ON ... ` syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You select columns from the table `Employee` while the requirement is to get the manager's details. 
You can do it with an `INNER JOIN` between the 2 tables, `GROUP BY m.mid, m.name` and aggregation:

```
SELECT 
  m.mid as ID, 
  m.name as Name, 
  MAX(e.office) office 
FROM Manager m INNER JOIN Employee e
ON e.mid = m.mid 
GROUP BY m.mid, m.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT e.office) = 1
```

The statement `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT e.office) = 1` sets the condition that all employees share 1 office. 
I guess there is a column in the `Employee` table like `mid` that references the employee's manager id. Change it to the name of the actual column.